# Subtract values of same column of a table depending on other column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a tabe `InvoiceOrderDetails`. It has following columns:

```
InvoiceNumber
RecType
Amount
ProjectCode
```

There can be multiple invoice numbers for the same `projectCode`. The `RecType` indicates that whether full payment has been made by client or not.

For example: total invoice amount for `Project XYZ` is 9000$. Client paid the first installment of 3000$. Now the next invoice which will be sent to client is of 6000$. Also, if `Rectype` is 1 means full payment is done else there's still a balance pending.

Now I have to create a computed column and display it in a grid where I want to show the remaining amount to client. That means, I have to check `RECTYPe` for all the invoices, grouped by `ProjectCode` and subtract the amount where with `Rectype` 1 from the amount with rectype 2.

I am not able to get how to compute the column and display in the grid. I am using Asp.Net (C# 2010) along with SQL Server 2008.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are binding to a grid, in the grid's row databound event you can calculate the total of all invoices and store it as a global variable. This would give you a total of the invoices at the end.

if you were to do a running total column, then in the same databound event you would set the value of a label in that column equal to the calculated value so far minus the total of the project.